# why the sigma algebra generated by null set and Brownian Motion is right continuous?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I mean why the generated one satisfies the definition of right continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the following result, I quote from [Karatzas/Shreve](http://books.google.ch/books?id=ATNy_Zg3PSsC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> For a $d$-dimensional strong Markov Process $X=\{X_t;\mathcal{F}_t^X;t\ge 0\}$ with initial distribution $\mu$, the augmented filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t^\mu\}$ is right-continuous.

This is Proposition 2.7.7. in Karatzas and Shreve. Since Brownian Motion has the strong Markov Property, you get your desired result. A proof of this can also be found in the book.

Comment: The proof seems to be quite complex than I imagined.Thank you very much!